# How to start a CupertinoSliverRefreshControl from flutter initState(){}

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show CupertinoSliverRefreshControl for showing initial loading.

This could be achieved in Material RefreshIndicator like this 
`refreshKey.currentState.show();` 
in my `init()` method 
But for Cupertino there's no such method show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently is not possible, upvote [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31376) issue to give it some more attention.

An alternative would be to create your own version (for instance by copying the flutter code and adjusting it)